# Load multiple random values from list into template

Tags: python, django

I need to apply a color class for every object I have in my template. This value must be randomly selected so there's different colors for each object. I have some code now which selects a random color from my list but it's the same for every single object in my template, which I don't want. I want it to be mixed. How can i consult this?

Views:

```
import random
color_list = ['purple', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
colors = random.choice(color_list)
return render(request, 'dashboard.html',{'color':colors,})
```

Template: 
person

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use [**`choice`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html#random.choice) here, but [**`shuffle`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

```
import random

color_list = ['purple', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
random.shuffle(color_list)
return render(request, 'dashboard.html',{'colors':color_list})
```

Now the order of the `color_list` is shuffled, You might need to use a `zip` however to assign a color to each object. Furthermore if the number of objects is larger than the number of colors, you will need to find a way to solve that.

Comment: What's a zip? I'm only familiar with the archiving zips. Care to explain? You're correct that this method doesn't assign a different color to each object.

Comment: @LesnieSncheider: the idea is that you take two (or more iterables), like `[1,4,2,5]` and `['b', 'd', 'k', 'r']`, and you create an iterable of tuples like `list(zip([1,4,2,5], ['b', 'd', 'k', 'r']))` is `[(1, 'b'), (4, 'd'), (2, 'k'), (5, 'r')]`.